# LEFT & RIGHT in SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I am learning it to become a data analyst. How do I select a certain number of strings within a column with SQL? For example, with spreadsheets I can use the LEFT & RIGHT functions. Is there an equivalent in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function called substring.

```
select SUBSTRING(Desc,2,len(desc)) from Table1
```

More info on
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp